# python error: InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite

I'm working on my python script as I'm trying to store a list of ids and values into sqlite3 database. I have got a problem with the code.

When I try this:

```
#create the buttons in the database
cur.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS buttons(button_ids TEXT, button_width TEXT)')
programs_button = [elem.control for elem in self.program_buttons]
program_id = list()
program_width = list()

#generating the program button ids
for generate_ids in range(3002, 3485):
    program_id.append(generate_ids)
print program_id

for elem in programs_button:
    program_width.append(elem.getWidth())
print program_width
#store the buttons in the database
cur.execute("INSERT INTO buttons(button_ids, button_width)" + " VALUES(?, ?)", [program_id, program_width])
```

It give me the error:

```
18:12:24 T:5328   ERROR: Exception in thread All_Channels_BACKUP_thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\XBMC\system\python\Lib\threading.py", line 532, in __bootstrap_inner
self.run()
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\XBMC\addons\script.tvguide\test.py", line 7661, in run
self.xtarget()
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\XBMC\addons\script.tvguide\test.py", line 1185, in All_Channels_BACKUP
cur.execute("INSERT INTO buttons(button_ids, button_width)" + " VALUES(?, ?)", [program_id, program_width])
InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.
```

The error are jumping on this line:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO buttons(button_ids, button_width)" + " VALUES(?, ?)", [program_id, program_width])
```

Here is a list of program_id data:

```
16:44:50 T:1296  NOTICE: [3002, 3003, 3004, 3005, 3006, 3007, 3008, 3009, 3010, 3011, 
3012, 3013, 3014, 3015, 3016, 3017, 3018, 3019, 3020, 3021, 3022, 3023, 3024, 3025, 3026, 
3027, 3028, 3029, 3030, 3031, 3032, 3033, 3034, 3035, 3036, 3037, 3038, 3039, 3040, 3041, 
3042, 3043, 3044, 3045, 3046, 3047, 3048, 3049, 3050, 3051, 3052, 3053, 3054, 3055, 3056, 
3057, 3058, 3059, 3060, 3061, 3062, 3063, 3064, 3065, 3066, 3067, 3068, 3069, 3070, 3071, 
3072, 3073, 3074, 3075, 3076, 3077, 3078, 3079, 3080, 3081, 3082, 3083, 3084, 3085, 3086, 
3087, 3088, 3089, 3090, 3091, 3092, 3093, 3094, 3095, 3096, 3097, 3098, 3099, 3100, 3101, 
3102, 3103, 3104, 3105, 3106, 3107, 3108, 3109, 3110, 3111, 3112, 3113, 3114, 3115, 3116, 
3117, 3118, 3119, 3120, 3121, 3122, 3123, 3124, 3125, 3126, 3127, 3128, 3129, 3130, 3131, 
3132, 3133, 3134, 3135, 3136, 3137, 3138, 3139, 3140, 3141, 3142, 3143, 3144, 3145, 3146, 
3147, 3148, 3149, 3150, 3151, 3152, 3153, 3154, 3155, 3156, 3157, 3158, 3159, 3160, 3161, 
3162, 3163, 3164, 3165, 3166, 3167, 3168, 3169, 3170, 3171, 3172, 3173, 3174, 3175, 3176, 
3177, 3178, 3179, 3180, 3181, 3182, 3183, 3184, 3185, 3186, 3187, 3188, 3189, 3190, 3191, 
3192, 3193, 3194, 3195, 3196, 3197, 3198, 3199, 3200, 3201, 3202, 3203, 3204, 3205, 3206, 
3207, 3208, 3209, 3210, 3211, 3212, 3213, 3214, 3215, 3216, 3217, 3218, 3219, 3220, 3221, 
3222, 3223, 3224, 3225, 3226, 3227, 3228, 3229, 3230, 3231, 3232, 3233, 3234, 3235, 3236, 
3237, 3238, 3239, 3240, 3241, 3242, 3243, 3244, 3245, 3246, 3247, 3248, 3249, 3250, 3251, 
3252, 3253, 3254, 3255, 3256, 3257, 3258, 3259, 3260, 3261, 3262, 3263, 3264, 3265, 3266, 
3267, 3268, 3269, 3270, 3271, 3272, 3273, 3274, 3275, 3276, 3277, 3278, 3279, 3280, 3281, 
3282, 3283, 3284, 3285, 3286, 3287, 3288, 3289, 3290, 3291, 3292, 3293, 3294, 3295, 3296, 
3297, 3298, 3299, 3300, 3301, 3302, 3303, 3304, 3305, 3306, 3307, 3308, 3309, 3310, 3311, 
3312, 3313, 3314, 3315, 3316, 3317, 3318, 3319, 3320, 3321, 3322, 3323, 3324, 3325, 3326, 
3327, 3328, 3329, 3330, 3331, 3332, 3333, 3334, 3335, 3336, 3337, 3338, 3339, 3340, 3341, 
3342, 3343, 3344, 3345, 3346, 3347, 3348, 3349, 3350, 3351, 3352, 3353, 3354, 3355, 3356, 
3357, 3358, 3359, 3360, 3361, 3362, 3363, 3364, 3365, 3366, 3367, 3368, 3369, 3370, 3371, 
3372, 3373, 3374, 3375, 3376, 3377, 3378, 3379, 3380, 3381, 3382, 3383, 3384, 3385, 3386, 
3387, 3388, 3389, 3390, 3391, 3392, 3393, 3394, 3395, 3396, 3397, 3398, 3399, 3400, 3401, 
3402, 3403, 3404, 3405, 3406, 3407, 3408, 3409, 3410, 3411, 3412, 3413, 3414, 3415, 3416, 
3417, 3418, 3419, 3420, 3421, 3422, 3423, 3424, 3425, 3426, 3427, 3428, 3429, 3430, 3431, 
3432, 3433, 3434, 3435, 3436, 3437, 3438, 3439, 3440, 3441, 3442, 3443, 3444, 3445, 3446, 
3447, 3448, 3449, 3450, 3451, 3452, 3453, 3454, 3455, 3456, 3457, 3458, 3459, 3460, 3461, 
3462, 3463, 3464, 3465, 3466, 3467, 3468, 3469, 3470, 3471, 3472, 3473, 3474, 3475, 3476, 
3477, 3478, 3479, 3480, 3481, 3482, 3483, 3484]
```

Here is the list of program_width data:

```
01:35:37 T:340  NOTICE: [342, 879, 879, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 
342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 879, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 
342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 879, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 
342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 879, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 
342, 342, 342, 342, 879, 342, 342, 879, 342, 691, 342, 342, 879, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 
879, 879, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 879, 342, 879, 342, 342, 691, 342, 342, 879, 342, 
342, 342, 342, 342, 879, 879, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 879, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 
342, 342, 342, 691, 342, 342, 879, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 879, 879, 342, 342, 342, 342, 
691, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 879, 879, 342, 342, 342, 
879, 342, 691, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 879, 879, 342, 
342, 342, 879, 342, 691, 342, 342, 342, 879, 879, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 879, 879, 342, 
342, 342, 879, 342, 691, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 
342, 342, 879, 342, 342, 342, 342, 879, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 
342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 879, 342, 691, 342, 342, 342, 879, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 
342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 879, 879, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 
342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 
342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 879, 879, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 
342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 879, 879, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 
342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 879, 879, 342, 342, 342, 
342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 691, 342, 342, 342, 
342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 
342, 342, 342, 342, 691, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 
342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 691, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 
342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 
342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 879, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 
342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 
342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 879, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 
342, 342, 342]
```

Here is the full code:

```
 # set the channels text
 for index in range(0, CHANNELS_PER_PAGE):
     #get the programs list
     cur = con.cursor()
     cur.execute('SELECT channel, title, start_date, stop_date FROM programs WHERE channel=?', [channel])
     programs = cur.fetchall()


     for ind, row in enumerate(programs):
         program = row[1].encode('ascii'), str(row[2]), str(row[3])
         title = row[1].encode('ascii')
         program_start_date = str(row[2])
         program_end_date = str(row[3])

         #create width size for per program button
         if program_length >= 10 and program_length <= 60:
             program_width = 342.06
         elif program_length >= 60 and program_length <= 90:
             program_width = 691.09
         elif program_length >= 90 and program_length <= 105:
             program_width = 879.10   


    self.program_buttons.append(ProgramControls(program_controls, program))
cur.close()
#create the buttons in the database
cur.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS buttons(button_ids TEXT, button_width TEXT)')
programs_button = [elem.control for elem in self.program_buttons]
program_id = list()
program_width = list()

#generating the program button ids
for generate_ids in range(3002, 3485):
    program_id.append(generate_ids)
print program_id

for elem in programs_button:
    program_width.append(elem.getWidth())
print program_width
#store the buttons in the database
cur.execute("INSERT INTO buttons(button_ids, button_width)" + " VALUES(?, ?)", [program_id, program_width])
```

The type of data for the `program_id` and `program_width` is a actual list.

Do you know why I have got the error and do you know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't insert a list into a DB. Instead, you have to do one of two things:

1. Create a row for each pair by inserting each pair. You can use [`.executemany()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.executemany) to do this efficiently.
2. Serialize your lists and store them as single raw text strings for the entire list, then when you read them out of the database, deserialize the strings. To do this you can use whatever serialization mechanism you want, but [`json`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) is a fairly straightforward option.

Comment: thank you, what do you mean that I can use `.executemany()`? can you please give me an example what is the correct way to use?

Comment: however, when I try this: `cur.executemany("INSERT INTO buttons(button_ids, button_width)" + " VALUES(?, ?)", [program_id, program_width])`, it give me the error: `ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 2, and there are 483 supplied.`. Any idea?

Comment: can you please tell me how I can use to create a row for each pair by inserting each pair?

Comment: Patience. o_O Anyhow, the correct format is not two lists, each of a ton of elements, it's one list, with a ton of pairs. In other words, instead of `[[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]` you want `[[1,4], [2,5], [3,6]]`. You can get the former from the latter by using `zip()`.

Answer (score 0):

To insert a single row in the table you need to call `cur.execute()` with `"INSERT INTO buttons(button_ids, button_width) VALUES(?, ?)"` as its first argument and a two-element tuple as its second argument. The first element of the tuple will substitute for the first parameter marker, the second for the second parameter marker. Your call provide a list rather than a single value for each of the element values.

To insert many rows in the table you should call `cur.executemany()` with the same first argument. The second argument, however, should be a *sequence of two-element tuples*, each of which should contain an id value as its first element and a button-width as its second.

Since you currently have `program_id`s and `program_width`s in separate lists, the first thing to do is make a list of two-element tuples, each containing the corresponding elements for each list. That would be

```
values = zip(program_id, program_width)
```

Once you have done this you can use values as the second argument to `execute_many()`, as in

```
cur.executemany("INSERT INTO buttons(button_ids, button_width) VALUES(?, ?)", values)
```

Don't forget to commit the changes when you are done.

Comment: thank you for your advice, i can see what the problem is. How I can split the strings in the list to allow me to print for each line of string from the list?

Comment: when i try this: `print program_id.split(",")`, it give me the error `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'`. do you have any idea how to fix this?